# How to access Livewire Component Variable then pass it to another Component

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to create a table with livewire that shows user profile cards (as modal) when pressing the table row.

In the livewire rendered component to trigger the code

```
@foreach($dataAlumnis as $alumni)
 <tr wire:click="showUserProfileCard({{$alumni->id}})"
```

And the function

```
public $dataAlumni;
public showingUserProfileCard = false;
*
*
public function showUserProfileCard(User $alumni){
        $this->dataAlumni = $alumni;
        /*/ dd($this->dataAlumni); <-- manage to correctly get the correct user data /*/ 
        $this->showingUserProfileCard = true;
    }
```

Now still in the rendered page

```
<x-modal maxWidth="fit" wire:model="showUserProfileCard">
        <x-profile-card/>
</x-modal>
```

I have `user` props in `<x-profile-card/>`  (regular blade component) that I want to fill with `$this->dataAlumni` from the Livewire Component. Is there a way I can do this?

I tried using `$alumni` as the props but it only shows the last rendered `$alumni` from the loop `<x-profile-card :user="$alumni"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
<x-profile-card :user="$dataAlumni"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I thought the wire:model should be called on the card to access the variable turns out it doesn't have to.

Comment: Yeah, you can use any public properties of livewire component as a variable in the blade